# What data structure should I use if I want to search an object in different ways according to different attributes?

Tags: java, object, data-structures

I'm programming in java, but that's just a detail.
I have  this object person class with attributes like: name, age, weight... And I need to have people stored in my application and being able to search them. Now, I can search them by name, age, weight... all that person's attributes. What's the best data structure/implementation that allows me to do this efficiently?

Comment: SQL with in memory database.

Answer (score 1):

[K-D tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Operations_on_k-d_trees) is a good choice for that. It partitions multi-dimensional data (any object with multiple attributes), and enables binary search tree like O(logN) search complexity. However, this will require few modifications to main variant.

If you don't know about it yet, go read about it first. So now you know, K-D tree doesn't exactly allow that `"Given name="John Doe",find the guy"` kind of queries. Instead, what it allows is `"given this entire John Doe guy, find who is *closest* to him"`.

At every level of the tree, it chooses left or right  sub-tree based on corresponding dimension of that level. But for 1st kind of query, your data for all dimensions except one is null. So, to search, you create an input object anyway with special dummy data for all but that one dimension. In your search function, when you encounter those special data, you carry on search on both sub-trees. Instead of closeness, unlike K-D tree, you can check for exact match.

You are unlikely to see the effect of this data structure if you are dealing with small amount of data. Interestingly though, when you search against more than 1 attribute, like `"given age=20 and name = "John", find the guy(s)"`, the search will be lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

What's your end-goal? If you just want to see trends between different people ad-hoc, I'd recommend just using R or Python PANDAS. That way you can quickly look up, compare, and visualize groups/individuals based on different attributes.

If you want to make an application in Java with multiple searchable options, and you don't care too much about space, I'd use multiple hash tables, with each hash corresponding to a different attribute. Have the values in an array be pointers pointing to a person. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

K is your attribute (age, sex, etc.) and V are pointers to people.